# asp, sql ms access, Select distinct names from category but show all subcats

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, distinct

I am newbie at SQl.
I am creating a small website using an ms access db.

I have a 2 tables,

**categories**

```
cat_id
cat_title
cat_description
```

**subcats**

```
subcat_id
subcat_catid
subcat_url
```

on the front page i want to display cat_title as the title (only once).
Then on a jump menu i want to be able to see all the url_sports relevant to that cat.

At the moment although i use the following code below i am still see the the sports cats repeated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT categories.cat_id,
                categories.cat_title,
                Subcats.subcat_catid,
                Subcats.subcat_url,
                categories.cat_description
FROM   categories
       INNER JOIN Subcats
               ON categories.cat_id = Subcats.subcat_catid;
```

Comment: if you have more than one Subcats.subcat_url for one subcats_catid then that's what is causing more than one row to display regardless the use of distinct

Comment: You should do the formatting at the application layer rather than in the database query.  MS Access (among databases) is uniquely unsuited to this type of formatting.

Comment: hi there can anybody show me how?